# mobx observable field for class type isn't working

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am using MobX 6+ in my project and I have a class with an `@observable` annotated field that contains class type.
I initialize the type with:

```
class MyClass {

    @observable myObservableField = ClassToInitialize;


    problemHere() {

         ....

         const MyType = this.myObservableField;
         const TypeInstance = new MyType(); // <-- Error is thrown at this line

         ....
    }
}

class ClassToInitialize {
     constructor() {
         ....
     }
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor IgnoreRegion cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the issue, it appears to happen due to MobX wrapping the field in a proxy function.

In order to solve the issue, use `shallow`:

```
class MyClass {

    @observable.shallow myObservableField;
    ....
}
```